# media queries for email signature, possible?

Tags: css, email, media-queries, html-email

I understand that media queries in html emails are not widely supported, but what about html email signatures? i've tried using this bit of code:

```
<style type="text/css">

    img#banner{display:block !important;
    }

    @media (max-width: 450px){

    img#banner{display:none !important;}
    }

</style>
```

putting it right before my opening table tag that contains the content for the signature, works in a browser, but it doesn't seem to work in email clients. I might be doing something wrong OR it might not be supported at all? I'm not sure? But if it were supported, even if in only a few email clients, it would be worth using.

Edit:
I've set the width of my banner to be 100%, since the banner graphic is too wide and looks a bit ugly on mobile devices the idea is to have it not show at all.

```
<a class="link" href="http://www.website.com/">
    <img id="banner" style="width:100%;" alt="#" src="banner.gif">
</a>
```

Edit 2:
Seems that the 2 !important tags were bad practive i have included a revised media query here:

```
<style type="text/css">

    img#banner{display:block;
    }

    @media (max-width: 450px){

    img#banner{display:none;}
    }

</style>
```

Although really this doesn't seem to work any better. I think the general consensus is that media queries and email signatures don't mix.

Comment: Media queries only works if you specify the device width inside the header.

Comment: Yes i've set the width of the header to 100%, so that should work. I just want the banner to not show on mobile devices as it gets too small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think that you can use media query in e-mails.
[Here is a link](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/media_queries_in_html_emails)

However, you can still manage to modify your html and CSS to maybe cover your image in order to center it for every devices.

To scale the background image to fit inside the div:

```
background-size: contain;
```

To scale the background image to cover the whole div:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Thanks for the link! This article comes to the conclusion that for iphone and ipad mail, media queries work. Although from my tests this doens't seem to be true. As far as i can tell my media queries are correct and quite simple. ps: thanks for the backgrounds size tip, though i don't think this will be helpful for what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Have you tried to removed the !important tag? Note: your code won't work on gmail

Comment: There is another important factor in using media queries, and it is "how you -send- the email". See, if I send a webpage as an email from Safari, media queries will remain intact; If I send the same html code form a marketing campaigns tool, like cakemail, media queries get changed and stop working + probably break the layout. 

For now, email media queries aren't standard enough, I'd recommend using % widths for your layout.

Browser wise, and this will surprise you, outlook.com is the best at rendering responsive emails. Yahoo mail tries it's best but requires some hacks in your queries.

Comment: Thanks Romain and Lacorne, i think i'm being too ambitious with these media queries, so i might go for a different solution, using background images maybe, although i know that that is a different world of pain altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Delete that `!important` rule on your first style for `display:block;`. Having two going head to head often has unexpected results.

Comment: Also you really should inline `display:block;` because of gmail stripping all style tags.